# How can I heal with arrows?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Watching [Technoblade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vixTohgROZ4), he mentions how bad tipped arrows are in Minecraft, saying that the Arrow of Healing isn't helpful.

Are there ways to actually heal properly with an Arrow of Healing (at least gain a few hearts)?

Comment: OTOH they are pretty powerful against undead creatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Healing), **Arrows of Healing give the same amount of health as their potion counterparts, but the healing effect can be cancelled out by the damage inflicted by the arrow.** But, it is possible to gain a slight amount of health, as long as you shoot an arrow weakly and are wearing good armor, as potion effects go through armor of all types.

Answer (score 1):

Arrows of Healing aren't really for players, but should be used on hostile mobs that take damage due to the Instant Healing effect.

But if you **really** want to get some hearts, then use Healing II.

In Bedrock though, low-range shooting of yourself results in 0.5 hearts, Healing or not.